# HTML Progress is not coming properly in Email

Tags: html

I am trying to display the progress of jobs running on a Linux server on an email using HTML Progress. My code looks like

When I run the below command `cat zxc.tmp | /usr/sbin/sendmail r***@gmail.com`, I can see only "Batch Progess" key word in the mail subject. Progress bar is not getting displayed.

Comment: My Code looks like                                                                                            
 MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7BIT
Content-Disposition: inline
<html>
<body>
Batch progress:
<progress value="12" max="13"></progress>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Please do not comment your own question, but feel free to edit it when adding new information. You should consider posting here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ok. Thanks Jonathan Hamel

Comment: Looking here https://quip.com/aO0pAZO9m9SG, it seems that the <progress> tag is not a whitelisted tag for Gmail. Consider using a table with background fills on your table cells instead..

Comment: Ok thanks.. I will try that. :-)

Comment: Ramkumar, did you find an answer to your problem? Feel free to post it here